# Original papers in algebraic topology

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

I am looking for the original papers in algebraic topology which primarily led to the development of what is found in many of the introductory
texts in algebraic topology: topics like homotopy and homology. Could anyone suggest such papers? My aim is to be aware of having a sense of how these topics developed and in what order and in the process also read some of the original papers. I hope it is not an unreasonable request. Thanks!

Comment: These slides mention some of the history of homotopy theory. Not exactly specific articles, but topics like * Cauchy and mobility of path, 1825;
* Riemann and connectivity, 1851;
* Jordan and deformations of curves, 1866-1882

Comment: It's not unreasonable at all, but it is quite difficult to address. The notation used in the early papers is different than the modern one and it took some time to get the right emphasis on the pivotal ideas and machinery. So, while reading original papers has its merits, I'm not sure how useful it's going to be in this context. Perhaps later on, once you have some mastery of the elements of algebraic topology. Do keep in mind though that there are several books devoted to, or which include, the history of (algebraic) topology.

Comment: Poincare's "Dernieres pensees" contains many of the foundational ideas of modern topology.

Comment: This looks more https://hsm.stackexchange.com 's thing.

Comment: Whe I was a research student I was strongly recommended the Introduction , and only the Introduction, to S,. Lefschetz's "Introduction to Topology",

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I don't see a link but you were probably referring to http://www.mit.edu/~ivogt/HisMathSeminar_HomotopyTheory.pdf .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you start with these books and the references they cite:

- *History of Topology*,  edited by James.
- *History of Algebraic and Differential Topology*, by Dieudonné.

Try also these accounts:

- [A Brief, Subjective History of Homology and Homotopy Theory in This Century](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2689545), by Peter Hilton.
- [A Brief History of Homotopy Theory](http://www.mit.edu/~ivogt/HisMathSeminar_HomotopyTheory.pdf) by Isabel Vogt.

Comment: Thank you. Both the books seem to very comprehensive. They aren't elementary, which means that I will keep coming back as I learn more about the subject.